# Model's wrist shrinking with IK arm rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to animate a shot where my character looks at the palm of their hand, but the wrist shrinks when its rotated.
I know the rotation should really be in the forearm but I don't know how to do that since I'm using an IK rig.
I have tried adding a separate wrist bone that's parented to the forearm and has a copy rotation constraint on the hand bone, but then the forearm also started shrinking.
[image: wrist bone constraints]
[image: Wrist and Arm shrinking]

Here is how thick the wrist and forearm should be for context
[image: Proper wrist and forearm]

How do I have the forearm rotate like this, without the wrist and forearm shrinking?

The blend file can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KJRAsMmiiQ8bLNMm1h40eMFkKxLiPGHY/view?usp=sharing

I know there is a similar post like this on stack exchange from a few years ago but it wasn't properly answered with anything other than theory. To quote that post, "I don't know how there isn't a youtube tutorial for this"